# Is there a way to console.log multiple variables using a single line of code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

What I am trying to do is print a bunch of variables using console.log.

```
let country = "India";
let continent = "Asian";
let population = "1.3 Billion";
        `
```

For instance, I want to print all of this at once. I don't want to console.log everything. Is there a way to do it using a single code?

Comment: What is "everything"? Do realise that there is a *lot* in JavaScript that holds some state, certainly when you run in a browser. For example, the whole DOM, the current time, ...

Comment: My bad I didn't elaborate more. By "everything" I mean a lot of "variables" at once? I did try using commas in console.log but I think it adds some irrelevant spacing. When I console.log each variable individually it prints perfectly. I don't' know what's happening there.

Comment: You can do `console.log({country, continent, population})`: then you get an expandable object representation in the console. There are many ways you can deal with this.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass multiple parameters to [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Console/log). So

```js
let country = "India";
let continent = "Asian";
let population = "1.3 Billion";

console.log(country, continent, population)
```

will print all three strings.

If you want more formatting options, you could for instance use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```js
let country = "India";
let continent = "Asian";
let population = "1.3 Billion";

console.log(`country: ${country}  continent: ${continent}  population: ${population}`)
```

You can also create an object containing your variables as properties.

```js
let country = "India";
let continent = "Asian";
let population = "1.3 Billion";

console.log({country, continent, population});
```