# Can we add multiple console.log to get output of the multiple logs in a single line inside Browser's console?

Tags: javascript, object, browser, compilation, console.log

As we all know that the **Browser's Console** output shows only 1-*Log* in a single line. It automatically changes the other `console.log()`  output in a new line or next line. Is there any way/trick/method to print multiple `console.log()` output by appending some `console.log()` and view the result(*all logs*) in a single line inside **Browser's Console**??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to console.log multiple variables using a single line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155961/is-there-a-way-to-console-log-multiple-variables-using-a-single-line-of-code-in)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your post, are you looking for the newline character `\n` ? eg `console.log("line 1\nline 2")`

Comment: I want to print two ```console.log``` in a single line like this:

 e.g:- ```console.log('This is')``` + ```console.log('Raj')``` = **This is Raj**

Comment: Unfortunately, ``console.log()`` does not work that way, but as mentioned in one of the comments why not append everything to a variable and at the end log the variable.

by the way you can override the console.log function and add your own. be carefull what you do when you attemp! 

Answer (score 0):

you can use console.log`('test-1', 'test-2', 'test-3')` for show multiple log

Comment: I want to print two ```console.log``` in a single line like this: e.g:- ```console.log('This is')``` + ```console.log('Raj')``` = **This is Raj**

Comment: console.log('this is', 'Raj');

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```js
let name = "xyz";
let age = "23";
let sex = "Male";
console.log(` Name : ${name}
 Age: ${age}
 Sex: ${sex}`)
```

Here The `${}` syntax is used to embed a value into our string and `` backtick  for multiline Template literals.

Comment: I want to print two ```console.log``` in a single line like this: e.g:- ```console.log('This is')``` + ```console.log('Raj')``` = **This is Raj**

Comment: I dont think it possible